# Get the JSON file every n minutes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, refresh

I have written code which gets the JSON file and work on it. But that file gets updated every 5 minutes. So I want my code to get the fresh data without causing refresh.

Here is how I am getting the JSON file.

```
    $.getJSON("new_json_file.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
//Here I am working on the data
});
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function and then it can use `setTimeout` to run itself again 5 minutes later...

```
function getData() {
    $.getJSON("new_json_file.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            //Here I am working on the data
        });
        setTimeout(getData, 300000);
    });
}
getData(); // run once to start it
```

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff (can mention you for some reason).  That was a schoolboy typo!

Comment: It breaks the code, I assume it's because it needs to call getData() from outside for the first time.

Comment: @user2798227 ya, looks like you are facing scope issue

Comment: What error do you get?  If it is a scope issue we'll need to see more code to help.

Comment: Hello, It is working, but it is appending my existing slide. It was supposed to replace. I am using Bootstrap button to display the JSON data. By using this code, it is appending buttons, it should replace the existing button with the new one depending on the data.

Comment: Try putting `$("#containerID").empty();` inside the success function, to empty the container element where you put the buttons (obviously change the ID to suit your selector).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there any other way to do the same. I think it can be done automatically when it takes the file using $.getJSON. I don't know properly, but I had read somewhere using Ajax. I haven't used it before so don't have much experience and just wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: Ajax is just a method of getting data from the server - it doesn't do anything to the page content at all - that's what the success callback function is for.  So emptying the container element before populating would be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. It had worked. I just wanted to learn another way if there was any.
Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

```
setInterval(30000, function() {

  $.getJSON("new_json_file.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
  //Here I am working on the data
  });
  });

});
```

Comment: `setInterval` is a not the best way to do this.  What if the success callback of `getJSON` takes longer than 5 minutes?

Comment: @Archer. You don't know that. I agree your solution is good. I'm just providing an alternative.
Don't get me wrong. But for argument sake, one could also say that setTimeout may not be the best way if it takes 4 minutes to fetch and I want the updates to show every 5 minutes. With your solution the updates will appear at every 9 minutes instead.
Although, I agree the calls won't overlap. I give you that.

Comment: I only said "what if", not that it *would* take longer.  It's highly unlikely, of course, but it needs to be mentioned.